# Two clustered SQL instances on one cluster - same port 1433?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, cluster, windows-cluster

Can two clustered SQL instances on a 2003 windows cluster use the same 1433 tcp port setting reliably?

It seems to be up and working right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft says no.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938) The named instance should technically not be listening on port 1433. If both instances are set to listen on the static port 1433 and it's working then maybe something in the cluster environment is allowing it. I'd be a little skeptical of it myself.

Comment: I've found a few other sources advising against it as well.  Each virtual sql server name has it's own IP so it seems it would be OK there.  My concern is what happens between the virtual sql server and the physical server - how that data is actually moved.

Answer (score 0):

We've actually had 3 instances running SQL 2005 in a Windows 2003 cluster for about 3 years using the default port settings and have had no issues at all. When running normally, we are running 2 instances on one node and 1 instance on the other and the failover has worked flawlessly as well.

Comment: Have you actually changed all the ports to 1433? The default port setting for named instances is to listen on dynamic ports.

Comment: They are all set to 1433, none were manually configured to this port.